# Set list to subset of pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I wish to set a list of lists in a column (say "B") for a subset of rows. Suppose my dataframe (df) looks like below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.random.randn(5)})
idx = df["A"] < 0
mylist = np.random.randint(0, 5, (idx.sum(), 3)).tolist()

df["B"] = None
```

First attempy was to do this which chucked an error: `df.loc[idx, "B"] = mylist`. The next attempt `df.loc[idx, "B"] = pd.Series(mylist)` ran but the values in the wrong place. The final thing I got to work was:

```py
df.loc[idx, "B"] = pd.Series(mylist, index=df.index[idx])
```

My question is, is this the only way of doing this? Feels like there might be a simpler way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: In my opinion your solution is nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `at` method, for example

```
my_list = [np.random.rand(5).tolist() for _ in range(6)]

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(-1,1,6)})
idx = np.where(test_df['A'] < 0)[0]
test_df['B'] = np.random.rand(len(my_list)).astype('object')

for ind in idx:test_df.at[ind,'B'] = my_list[ind]
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I feel like `at` should be a last resort. I've +1ed for the answer regardless. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This way should work fine:

```
df['B'].loc[idx]=mylist
```